# How to suppress the error and display only the final output of du Linux command

Tags: tail, du

Running du command displays following output -

```
[pz@texualp ~]$ du -s /My-Data/
du: cannot read directory ‘/My-Data/ROMANIEI/smart/store’: Permission denied
du: cannot read directory ‘/My-Data/ROMANIEI/smart/data’: Permission denied
du: cannot read directory ‘/My-Data/ROMANIEI/smart/temp’: Permission denied
du: cannot read directory ‘/My-Data/ROMANIEI/smart/spool’: Permission denied
2900883608      /My-Data/
[pz@texualp ~]$
```

What is the way to display the last line only (i.e. **2900883608      /My-Data/**)?

I have also tried - `du -s /My-Data/ | tail -n1`, but it did not work.

I would also like to know if there is any way to display only the size ( i.e. **2900883608** ).

Comment: To suppress errors, add a `2>/dev/null` at the end of the command.

Comment: Thanks dratenik. It worked. Is there a way to print only the first value (i.e. the number representing the size).

Comment: If you want just the number, add `| cut -f1`

Comment: Thank you so much dratenik. Both of your suggestions worked.

Answer (score 1):

As it mention in comments you should redirect the `STDERR` (where those errors are printed). And this can be done on this way:

```
du -s /My-Data/ 2>/dev/null
```

P.S. And if you do not have permission to read particular directory you will not get proper result, you will see the size only of directories where you have permissions.